# fork() in for() loop

Tags: c, fork

I'm trying to make a homework assignment where I have to use `fork()` but I don't know why I can't stop my forks after running them through my for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int limit = argc/2;
    if(argc%2 == 0){

            perror("the number of arguments given must pe even!");
            exit(1);
    }

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=limit; i++){
        if(fork()==-1){
            perror("childes couldn't be created\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(fork()==0){
            printf("fork: %d \n",i);
            exit(1);
        }
        wait(0);
    }


    printf("exiting...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
warzaru@ubuntu:~/OS/UprocH$ ./exe a b c d
fork: 0 
fork: 0 
fork: 1 
fork: 1 
fork: 1 
fork: 2 
fork: 2 
fork: 1 
fork: 2 
exiting...
exiting...
fork: 2 
exiting...
exiting...
fork: 2 
exiting...
exiting...
exiting...
warzaru@ubuntu:~/OS/UprocH$ fork: 2 
fork: 2 
fork: 2 
exiting...
```

Comment: You are forking twice in the same loop, you do know that?

Comment: Noop how come, were is that...? :<

Comment: you have created a fork bomb. You should do something like: pid = fork(); if (pid < 0) ... ; if (pid == 0) ....

Comment: `if(fork()==-1)` <- first fork, `if(fork()==0)` <- second fork. If the first fork works, it will continue spawning new forks as well. thus creating two forks within one loop, which will loop again, so you now have a parent process/thread that loops again and an extra child process that forks again

Comment: I ain't a C guru so I will let them provide a correct answer though :-)

Comment: @DaanTimmer Hey, you're dead on, go ahead and answer it.

Comment: please help... i`m pretty unclear with the proces....  i know `-1` is returned if error(couldnt be forked) i know if `fork() == 0` and i know the return of a fork process is  its pid... but how can i manipualte them in for loop :<

Comment: lol the 2 ifs made me problem it seems like it works now

Comment: @DanielFischer If you say so :-). Only C I've worked with is with microcontrollers, they don't have no fork() there ;-). I happen to know the fork() quirks from Python :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Daniel Fischer forced me to provide an answer.

Change:

```
if(fork()==-1){} // first fork
if(fork()==0){}  // second fork
```

To:

```
pid = fork();
if(pid == -1)
{
    ... //failed
}
else if(pid == 0)
{
    ... //success
}
```

Or use a switch statement:

```
switch(fork())
{
    case -1:
        ... // failed
        break;
    case 0:
        ... // success
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! appreciated, and  you gaved em a good idea with switch :D

Comment: "forced" is a rather strong word ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use execl() or some other variant of exec, this ensures that the child being created does not inherit anything from the parent. This would allow you to create children with a for loop without going into an exponential child explosion. Modify the arguments of the execl function suitably and you can create 3 processes like:

```
main()
{
    int i,pid[3];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        pid[i]=fork();
        if (pid[i]==0)
            execl("path",0,0);
    }

    sleep(2);
}
```